# Connect Azure Pipelines to GitHub Enterprise

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a hosted GitHub Enterprise (GHE) account which needs to integrate with Azure Pipelines. I have installed the [Azure Pipelines app](https://github.com/marketplace/azure-pipelines) from the GitHub Marketplace for our GHE account. The installation of the Azure Pipelines app asks to select an Azure DevOps project and GHE repo to setup the integration. This results in one pipeline being connected to a GHE repo.

But my question is, how to we setup other pipelines within Azure DevOps to use repos in GHE?

Nowhere in the Azure Pipelines interface can I find an option to select a GHE repo. Only public GitHub and GitHub Enterprise (on-prem) server repos. It seems that only the Azure Pipelines app setup wizard allows you to configure a pipeline with a GHE.

I can't imagine that we would have to initiate the setup wizard of the Azure Pipelines app every time we want to connect a pipeline to a GHE repo. That wouldn't even be possible, because most coworkers won't have the permissions to do that. What am I missing?

Remark: I realize that we could create a service connection in Azure DevOps using on a Personal Access Token or username+password. But that's tied to someone's personal account. If that person would leave, the connection is broken. Unless you create a service/dummy account, which doesn't seem very elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the cause of the issue.

First of all, when you install the Azure Pipelines app from the GitHub marketplace, you first need to make sure that you select your GitHub organisation and not your personal account.

Secondly, during the installation you are taken to Azure DevOps to setup your project. Two different authorization pages will be shown; "*Azure Pipelines by Microsoft would like to [...]"* and the page for OAuth authorization. As can be seen in below image, there is a small **grant** button that's easily overlooked. You need to press that button before you press the large green that says *"Authorize AzurePipelines"*

[image: Press grant button before the big green button]

I am now able to select my GitHub Enterprise repositories when I create a new pipeline in Azure DevOps. I simply choose GitHub as the source where my repository lives.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GitHub Enterprise, then you can integrate with Azure AD. Then based on group membership you can assign access to repositories with the help of Github Teams.

Then based on those permissions the repos to which somebody has access will be visible during the setup of the Azure DevOps pipeline.

Some useful resources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/github-tutorial
- https://github.blog/2019-09-24-azure-active-directory-team-synchronization-now-available-with-enterprise-cloud/
- https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/about-teams
- https://enterprise.github.com/support

Comment: Hi Richard, this is helpful. Let me read and investigate if everything has been setup properly.